# Creating a PHP page that shows an image via last.fm API

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to do a PHP page to shows an album cover via Last.FM API. However, the Artist Name and the Title of the music are provided by a XML file that a software updates via FTP.

Here is the code of Last.FM api:

```
<?php
$img = simplexml_load_file('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=track.getInfo&api_key=<APIKEY>&artist=cher&track=believe');
echo '<img src="';
echo $img->track[0]->album[0]->image[3];
echo '">';
?>
```

Now the link of my XML file is: http://summerblast.pt/avaplayer/rds.xml
The info I need to the Last.FM API is in 'OnAir/CurMusic'.

Well, what I am trying to do is change "Cher" and "Believe" (the artist's name and the Title's name) in the link of the "simplexml_load_file" (in the php code) with the info that my XML file provides.

Can you please help me doing this?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Do you have the XML data from rds.xml in a variable already, or are you asking how to parse the XML?

Comment: I just have written the code like I published here. I don't know how to parse the XML. That's my problem.

Comment: Can you give us a example of what the XML being returned is, without it we can not help you without getting an API key.

Comment: Here is an example: http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=track.getInfo&api_key=4c4b816db869f706c12a003da5a3c19e&artist=cher&track=believe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry was confused to what you were asking from before. I have gone ahead and corrected to do what you wanted.

You can get the Artist and the Title from rds.xml and just pass it to the URL like the following listed below (note it is important to run `urlencode` on them since they can have spaces and other things to break the URL):

**Updated to do error checking**

```
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('http://summerblast.pt/avaplayer/rds.xml');
    $artist = urlencode($xml->OnAir->CurMusic->Artist);     
    $track =  urlencode($xml->OnAir->CurMusic->Title);
    $url = 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=track.getInfo&api_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&artist='.$artist.'&track='.$track;
    $xml2 = @simplexml_load_file($url);
    if ($xml2 === false) 
    {
        echo("Url failed"); // do whatever you want to do
    }
    else
    {
        if($xml2->track->album->image[3])
        {
            echo '<img src="';
            echo((string) $xml2->track->album->image[3]);    
            echo '">';
        }
        else
        {
            echo("artist does not have a image"); // do whatever you want to do
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. I need a PHP page that shows an image (wich is hosted in Last.FM servers) according with the information that my XML file provides (http://summerblast.pt/avaplayer/rds.xml - the artist and the title of the current song).

Comment: So, the image will not be the same everytime. It changes when my XML file changes too.

Comment: @dppires I am aware of that are you sure you are actually getting the XML? If you do echo( $img->asXML() ); Do you see the XML?

Comment: @dppires sorry did not understand the question from what your first asked, this should do what you were asking

Comment: Ok! This code sounds better than the other one. But, here it doesn't work.

Comment: What is not working for you? It works on my end. The current song does not have a image if that is confusing you.

Comment: Also it appears not all artist and tracks can be looked up. For example the current band is D.A.M.A and the track is LUISA. Which can not be be found with the URL ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=track.getInfo&api_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&artist=D.A.M.A&track=LUISA

Comment: @dppires I would just add in some error checking on the last part to make sure the call succeeded.

Comment: Right. Just one more thing. Can you help me with writting a part of this code to shows a default image if Last.FM doesn't have the requested image?